# jQuery hide popup when clicking outside of element or it's children not working

Tags: jquery, onclick

I can't get seem to figure out how hide the 'target' element when I click outside of it. The 'document' click event won't fire properly Any ideas?

```js
$(".contact").click(function() {
  $(".target").toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#menucontainer').length) {
    $(".target").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.target {
  display: none;
  border: solid grey 2px;
  box-shadow: grey 2px 2px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="contact btn btn-primary">Click </button>

<div id="menucontainer">
  <div class="target">carter</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works, you just need to check if the Button is clicked like in below:
`if(!$(event.target).closest('#menucontainer').length&&!event.target.classList.contains('contact')) {
  $(".target").hide();
}`

```js
$(".contact").click(function() {
  $(".target").toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
if(!$(event.target).closest('#menucontainer').length&&!event.target.classList.contains('contact')) {
  $(".target").hide();
}
});
```

```css
.target {
  display: none;
  border: solid grey 2px;
  box-shadow: grey 2px 2px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="contact btn btn-primary">Click </button>

<div id="menucontainer">
  <div class="target">carter</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I would have never have gotten this on my own.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why I need the and statement? I'm missing something very basic, but I don't know why I need to check that as well.

Comment: When you click the button, most the above function working and not the below.
so you need to check that you don't click the container and the toggle button

Comment: Okay, yes I see now. I have no idea how I missed that. Thanks!